# Hooking non windows api function with detours

Tags: x86, hook, calling-convention, detours

I want to hook a non windows api function in an executable (one time - not permanent), I found the function address (`0x2bf2ca5`) using a debugger , I'm using the following code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "detours.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

static int(*TrueFunc)(int unk1, int unk2, uint8_t unk3, uint8_t unk4, uint8_t unk5, uint8_t unk6, uint8_t unk7, uint8_t unk8, uint8_t unk9, uint8_t unk10, int unk11, int unk12, int unk13, int unk14) = (int(*)(int unk1, int unk2, uint8_t unk3, uint8_t unk4, uint8_t unk5, uint8_t unk6, uint8_t unk7, uint8_t unk8, uint8_t unk9, uint8_t unk10, int unk11, int unk12, int unk13, int unk14))(0x2bf2ca5);


int Hook_TrueFunc(int unk1, int unk2, uint8_t unk3, uint8_t unk4, uint8_t unk5, uint8_t unk6, uint8_t unk7, uint8_t unk8, uint8_t unk9, uint8_t unk10, int unk11, int unk12, int unk13, int unk14)
{
    printf("%c",unk8);
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    LONG error;
    (void)hinst;
    (void)reserved;

    if (DetourIsHelperProcess()) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {

        DetourRestoreAfterWith();


        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)TrueFunc, Hook_TrueFunc);
        error = DetourTransactionCommit();

        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("error=%u\n", error);
        }

    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)TrueFunc, Hook_TrueFunc);
        error = DetourTransactionCommit();

    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The parameters of the function are passed like so:

```
push    3Ch
mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_8]
push    ecx
mov     edx, [ebp+arg_4]
push    edx
push    0
sub     esp, 10h
mov     eax, esp
mov     ecx, [ebp+var_10]
mov     [eax], ecx
mov     edx, [ebp+var_C]
mov     [eax+4], edx
mov     ecx, [ebp+var_8]
mov     [eax+8], ecx
mov     edx, [ebp+var_4]
mov     [eax+0Ch], edx
push    16
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
push    eax
call    Func
```

the error i get from detours `DetourTransactionCommit()` is:

```
#define ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER          87L
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hard-code the function address like you have done since the address can change on each run due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) unless you have turned off ASLR using [/DYNAMICBASE:NO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=vs-2019) linker option or turned of ASLR in the OS itself.

Instead you should be assigning the function address using the function name as shown in detour's github [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/blob/master/samples/slept/slept.cpp#L18) or you can find the function address using DetourFindFunction as shown below.

```
PVOID pfTrueFunc = DetourFindFunction("dll or exe name which has original function", "TrueFunc");
DetourAttach(&pfTrueFunc , Hook_TrueFunc);
```

Comment: I know about ASLR, thats why I'm getting the address using a debugger on runtime, then attach the detour dll with the updated function address. The function I want doensn't have a symbol.